# Djangoの画像入力フォームの使い方がわからない

Tags: python, django

webページに画像入力フォームを表示することはできたのですが、その入力フォームに添付された画像をどのようにして使うかがわからなくこまっています。画像の情報を取り出したいと考えています

```
#view.py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post

def index(request):
params = {
        'form': PhotoForm(),            

    }
if (request.method == 'POST'):      
    params['form'] = PhotoForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
return render(request, 'cp4/index.html', params)
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms                                                           

class PhotoForm(forms.Form):
form = forms.ImageField()
```

## index.pyの一部

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Django 2であれば、基本的なアップロード処理がこのページで紹介されています。

[Django Documentation - ファイルのアップロード](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)

アップロードされたファイルの処理方法は、以下のように書いてあります。

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
・・・
```

> アップロードされたファイルをハンドルする一般的な方法は、次のようになります。

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

まずは、このページをよく読んでみて下さい。